# How to perform actions like search element and clicking buttons on tabs that are not active with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a website where I need to enter details submit then it opens a new tab but once a pop up shows on the previous tab need to press ok. The problem is i cannot find a way to find element and clock on button without using switch active tab it needs to run in the background. This function works fine only on the first original tab that is opened and not new tabs being opened.

```
while True:
    for handle in w.window_handles:
        try:
            print(w.window_handles)
            print (handle)
            popup = WebDriverWait(w, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "uir-message-buttons")))
            print(popup)
            time.sleep(.5)
            #ok = w.find_element_by_link_text("OK")
            WebDriverWait(w, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='OK']"))).click()
            #popup.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            #submit = w.find_element_by_link_text("Submit")
            #submit.click()
            WebDriverWait(w, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'submitter'))).click()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('Not found')

            time.sleep(.5)
```

So I need to list out the tabs if element in tab press button in tab then keep going without switching the active tab (meaning you shouldnt vissualy see the tab switch to perform the actions).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you can use `driver.switch_to.window()`